# Select first p tag containing an image, depending on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following lines of code in my website:

```
<div class="the-post-thumbnail">
    <img src="" alt="" width="" height="" />
</div>

<div class="post-body">
    <p><img src="" alt="" width="" height="" /></p>
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    <p><img src="" alt="" width="" height="" /></p>
</div>
```

How can I select the first **`<p>`** tag containing an image within the **`post-body`** div and hide it depending on if there is an image within the div for **`the-post-thumbnail`**, otherwise, show it ?

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdExzj?editors=101)

Comment: Only CSS? Or can use jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`:has()`**](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and **[`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)**

1. Using [**`:has()`**](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) you can select `p` tag which contains `img` tag
2. Use **[`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)** to first `p` tag from them
3. Use **[`hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/)** and **[`show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show/)** for toggling visibility

**CODE :**

```js
var ele = $('.post-body p:has(img):first');
if ($('.the-post-thumbnail img').length > 0)
  ele.hide();
else
  ele.show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="the-post-thumbnail">
  <img src="" alt="#" width="" height="" />
</div>

<div class="post-body">
  <p>
    <img src="" alt="#" width="" height="" />
  </p>
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  <p>
    <img src="" alt="" width="" height="" />
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyqoRB?editors=101 - This solution seems to work partially.  If I remove the image from within the `the-post-thubnail`, it removes the one within the `post-body` div also - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YygONe?editors=101

Comment: Thank you very much for your help +1

Comment: @user1752759 : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// $el will be the first p
$el = $("div.post-body").find("img").eq(0).closest("p");

if($(".the-post-thumbnail img").length==0)
  $el.hide(); 
else
  $el.show()
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQmgRB?editors=101 - Not too sure this solution is working.

Comment: I think it is working.. try removing the img from the upper div, it wont show you the image in the p tag as well